# Windows Phone Emulator not deploying

Tags: windows-phone-8

Current I am using **HP Probook 4530s** and i have enabled virtual machine in BIOS ,
But still Windows phone emulator is not deploying.

I have just loaded an empty project and deployed it first .
Continuously giving these errors

Error    1    Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
Exception - 0x80131500    App23
Error    2    Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
Exception - 0x80131500 App23

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here for the requirements for using the WP8 Emulator.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I know that Hyper-V is required to run the WP8 emulator, so if your laptop is not running Hyper-V it will not run the emulator.